# Efficient way to get the N largest values of a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I need to get the `w highest` values of a `column` groupying by Country.

The code below is working:

```
w = 100
df.groupby('country').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('x', ascending=False).head(w)
```

Is there a way to make this code more efficient?  My dataset is huge, like 30kk rows.

Comment: Does `df.groupby('country').apply(pd.value_counts).head(w)` work any better? (if it does work)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html)

```py
w = 100
df.groupby('country').nlargest(w)
```

According to the doc

> Faster than `.sort_values(ascending=False).head(n)` for small n relative to the size of the Series object.

Since your `w=100` is small relative to `30kk`, it will be faster.